# Editing a comment/object and saving it over the previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Here's the github if it helps](https://github.com/Ninety9Balloons/small-projects-react/blob/main/src/routes/CommentsSection/components/BottomButtons.jsx)

Right now I can click on the edit button of a comment, a textarea appears using the previous content of that comment to autofill it, but I'm not sure how to get it to save.

```
function handleEdit(e) {
    setEditing(!editing);
    setLoading(true);

    function editComment(id, arr) {
        arr.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (item.id == id) {
                item.content = (
                    <textarea
                        className="w-full h-[100px] bg-secondary border rounded p-3 outline-none"
                        placeholder="Edit a comment..."
                        defaultValue={item.content}
                    ></textarea>
                );
            } else if (item.replies && item.replies.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < item.replies.length; i++) {
                    if (item.replies[i].id == id) {
                        item.replies[i].content = (
                            <textarea
                                className="w-full h-[100px] bg-secondary border rounded p-3 outline-none"
                                placeholder="Edit a comment..."
                                defaultValue={item.replies[i].content}
                            ></textarea>
                        );
                        editComment(item.id, item.replies);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    editComment(e.target.id, comments);

    setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
    }, 100);
}
```

Here's the Edit/Save button

```
  <button
                    className="flex items-center gap-2 font-bold text-accent"
                    onClick={(e) => handleEdit(e)}
                    id={id}
                >
                    <img
                        src="assets/images/commentssection/icon-edit.svg"
                        alt="edit icon"
                    />
                    {editing ? "Save" : "Edit"}
                </button>
```

Comment: Linking to GitHub to your *main* branch does not help, since your question will be outdated once you fix it. You can keep all relevant code in the question. See [Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). If you have a form tag, prevent submitting the form. You can search how to do that here on SO.